How smartphones and smartwatches communicate?
I was wondering how phones and watches communicate with bluetooth? How does it handle incoming calls or notifications received on smartphones applications?

BLE allows to send and receive data and on this base someone built one or more protocols. I am not sure where to find the protocol specs and if the would be helpful for you. In the end this question seems to be more a programming question and there is a similar question of SO: Is there a common communication protocol between smartwatches and Android phones?
